# Can two behemoths spawn in the same game?

Tags: battlefield-1

Suppose Team 1 gets far enough behind that a behemoth spawns for them. Then, suppose that Team 1 captures all the objectives before (or after) their behemoth is destroyed and now Team 2 is hundreds of tickets behind. Will a behemoth spawn for Team 2 as well? If so, how much damage do behemoths do to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Wiki](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Behemoth#Battlefield_1):

- For Conquest:

> Only one Behemoth will appear during a match.

- For Operations:

> Each side may receive a behemoth, though at most one Behemoth may be active at any one time.

If only one can spawn at a time/at most, then they can't do damage to one another.

Comment: While this is a good start, I'm not sure if it answers the question definitively; the author may have just wanted to clarify that a team cannot have multiple behemoths.

Comment: @Ovi I've edited my answer for the game types - I didn't realize it was different among the game modes.

Comment: Oh okay thanks I didn't realize that either